# PHP validation for webservice

Tags: php, web-services, web, yii

I am a bit confused with a condition for writing a web services using php. I have a field `type` which should be `w` or `d`, nothing else. `w` is for weekdays like Monday, tuesday to Friday, and `d` is for dates like `2017-02-15`

Basically what I want is if

`type` = `w`
then 
`days` = `Monday` // It can be anything between Monday to Friday..

So how will i put validation for `days` field that i should be between Monday to Friday, It should give error if user enter anything else..?

Similarly if `type` = `d` then `days` = `2017-02-15` so if type is d and days should be a date like `2017-02-15` it should not be monday or any other characters or number, it should be a date.

This is what i have tried..

```
if (isset($this->inputs['day_type']) == 'w') {
    // w = Monday, Tuesday etc
    if (isset($this->inputs['days']) && !empty($this->inputs['days'])) {

        $campaign->days = $campaign->days;
    }
} elseif (isset($this->inputs['day_type']) == 'd') {
    if (isset($this->inputs['dates']) && !empty($this->inputs['dates'])) {
        $seperatingDates = explode(";", $this->inputs['dates']);
        $campaign->days = $seperatingDates;
    }
}
```

Comment: `isset` returns a bool, therefore you cannot compare it to a string. You have to do the comparison separately.

Comment: Then how will i check if user has enter anything? user may leave it empty, I dont want empty value to be saved. @MrDarkLynx

Comment: No, you can leave the `isset`, but you have to check for the value separately: `if (isset($this->inputs['day_type']) && $this->inputs['day_type'] == 'w')`

Comment: Alright, then what will be next condition, If he enters `w` then in `days` he enters a date instead of day like monday, How will i check ? He must enter  days not date if he used `w` for `day_type` @MrDarkLynx

Comment: You could check if the input string contains any numbers.

Comment: Why it should be a number, what if he enters any name of person, but input should be a week days monday, tuesday etc.. will this condition be ok? `if ($this->inputs['days'] == "monday" || $this->inputs['days'] == "tuesday" )`

Comment: That would work, yes. Although if the input started with a capital letter, like `Monday`, your approach would not work. You could convert the input to lowercase using [`strtolower()`](https://www.w3schools.com/php/func_string_strtolower.asp) and then check.

Answer (score -1):

You can use

```
if (isset($this->inputs['day_type']) && $this->inputs['day_type'] == 'w') {
    // w = Monday, Tuesday etc
    if (isset($this->inputs['days']) && !empty($this->inputs['days'])) {

        $campaign->days = $campaign->days;
    }
} 
elseif (isset($this->inputs['day_type']) && $this->inputs['day_type'] == 'd') {
    if (isset($this->inputs['dates']) && !empty($this->inputs['dates'])) {
        $seperatingDates = explode(";", $this->inputs['dates']);
        $campaign->days = $seperatingDates;
    }
}
```

**Explanation :**

`isset(value)` returns `true` if the value is set, otherwise it returns `false`.

So here you are checking if the post value( day_type ) exists and it equals `w`, then execute the first block of statements. And if value ( day_type ) is set and it equals `d`, then execute the second block of statements.

**UPDATE :**

Also you can simply use `switch..case` for the same :

```
$day_type = $this->inputs['day_type'];

switch($day_type)
{
     case 'w' : 
         if (isset($this->inputs['days']) && !empty($this->inputs['days'])) {
            $campaign->days = $campaign->days;
         }
         break;

     case 'd' : 
         if (isset($this->inputs['dates']) && !empty($this->inputs['dates'])) {
             $seperatingDates = explode(";", $this->inputs['dates']);
             $campaign->days = $seperatingDates;
         }
}
```